# Getting error while installing Cocoa pod into the M1 Mac mini

Tags: ios, macos, apple-m1

I have Mac mini with M1 chip. MacOS is Big Sur 11.2.1 .
I am trying to install cocoa pod into Mac mini I am getting the following error.

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle, 0x0009): missing compatible arch in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: I think you should post this question on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

Goto the following path.
'/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/'
and delete the 'date_core.bundle' bundle file and 'date.rb' file.

Go to the following path.
'/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/date-3.1.1/'
and delete the 'date_core.bundle' bundle file.

and try 'sudo gem install cocoapods' command on terminal.